# Creating PointCloud from std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have some points in a std::vector collection and I am trying to use that to create a pcl::PointCloud object. Looking at the documentation did not help me out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy element by element:

```
void CloudToVector(const std::vector<PointType>& inPointVector, PointCloud& outPointCloud)
{
    for(const PointType& point : inPointVector)
    {
        outPointCloud.push_back(point);
    }
}
```

---

UPD this should also work

```
void CloudToVector(const std::vector<PointType>& inPointVector, PointCloud& outPointCloud)
{
    outPointCloud.points = inPointVector;
}
```